# javascript regex backslash issue

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am attempting to come up with a regex that captures the following:

```
var testString = "one . one\.two . one\.two\.three" ;
testString.match(/(\\\.)|([^\.\[\]\s]+)/g  );
```

or perhaps using double-backslashes:

```
var testString = "one . one\\.two . one\\.two\\.three" ;
testString.match(/(\\\.)|([^\.\[\]\s]+)/g  );
```

and would yield:

> one
>
> one\.two
>
> one\.two\.three

or even better, eliminate the backslashes:

> one
>
> one.two
>
> one.two.three

But I am not sure how to look for a period but yet ignore a period that is trailing a backslash.

In other words, i am trying to manually build an object path.  if the path looked something like this:

`myObject.one.one_two.one_two_three`

it would be easy, but my object level-names have period characters in them.
so I am trying to split up a string by periods **that are not backslashed**.

i hope this makes sense.  thank you all very much.

Comment: The backslashes in the original string are only present in your notation, not in the actual string. Whether you remove them from the original string notation or not, it is the same string. So there is no way to detect whether you had a backslash in your notation or not. If you want them in your string, you need to double them in your notation.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `testString.split(/\s+\.\s+/)`? Then to remove the backslashes (if they are physical backslashes), `.map(x => x.replace("\\", "")`? By the way, is there some reason you are referring to backreferences in the title of your post? Also, minor point, but what is the purpose of `String()` here?

Comment: As @trincot points out, you have to distinguish between the use of a backslash within the notation for a string literal to escape characters, and actual backslashes in the string. The string literal notation `var testString = "one . one\.two . one\.two\.three" ;` results in a string `one . one.two . one.two.three`. The string literal notation `var testString = "one . one\\.two . one\\.two\\.three" ;` results in a string `one . one\.two . one\.two\.three`, where the backslashes are actual backslash characters within the string value..

Comment: i am modifying existing code so most of this is just a cut/paste - and your map suggestion worked great (very minor tweak):
`.map(x => x.replace(/\\/g, ""));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend the original to have literal backslashes in them, you need to escape them in your literal string notation, like this:

```
var testString = "one . one\\.two . one\\.two\\.three" ;
```

I will assume this is what you intended.

If the parts are always separated by space-dot-space, it is easier to just split the string by that.

In case this is not suitable for you (your general pattern is not always like that and/or you really need it to be a regular expression), you can use this variant of your regex:

```
/(\\\.|[^\s\.\\])+/g
```

```js
var testString = "one . one\\.two . one\\.two\\.three" ;
console.log('input:', testString);

var result = testString.match(/(\\\.|[^\s\.\\])+/g);

// Show result:
for (var match of result) {
    console.log('output:', match);
}
```

You can remove the backslashes afterwards with `match.replace(/\\\./g, '.')` in the above code.

Comment: thank you.  not to brag, but i was pretty close on my answer.
space-dot-space was just there to make it more readable.

Comment: Indeed, you were close. ;-)